# MySQL combine output data

Tags: mysql

I'm quite a newbie when it comes to MySQL. I'm having a hard time finding this one out, but I bet the solution is quite simple. I have the following tables:

movies

- movie_id
- movie_title

con_genres (connection table between the other 2)

- movie_id
- genre_id

genres

- genre_id
- name

I tried different queries but I keep getting these kind of results

```
1 | Avatar | Sci-fi
1 | Avatar | Fantasy
2 | Matrix | Sci-fi
2 | Matrix | Fantasy (this one is non existent)
```

But I want the following results

```
1 | Avatar | Sci-fi, Fantasy
2 | Matrix | Sci-fi
```

What's the best approach to get this through 1 query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Didn't run it, but this should work:

```
SELECT m.movie_id, MIN(m.movie_title), GROUP_CONCAT(g.name)
FROM movies m
LEFT JOIN con_genres c ON c.movie_id = m.movie_id
LEFT JOIN genres g ON c.genre_id = g.genre_id
GROUP BY m.movie_id
```

The idea here is to join the three tables (which would produce something like your first example result), group on movie id (obviously, since we only want one row per movie) and use [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to select all genre names for each movie in one comma-separated string.